# Outlook save only pdf attachments

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

Hi I have found this code and been using it for a while now but I am looking to add a rule to only save the PDF attachments and count how many PDF files have been saved.

I have got it saving all files and it loops the duplicated files but I just want it to save pdf files.

can someone assist please?

thanks

```
' ######################################################
'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.
' ######################################################
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
    Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.
    Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.
    Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.
    Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.
    Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.
    Dim Atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.
    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.
    Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.
    Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.
    Dim strFolderpath       As String       ' The selected folder path.
    Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.
    Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.
    Dim oItem               As Object
    Dim iAttachments        As Integer


    blnIsEnd = False
    blnIsSave = False
    lCountAllItems = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If Err.Number = 0 Then

        ' Get the handle of Outlook window.
        lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)

        If lHwnd <> 0 Then

            ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Select folder to save attachments:", _
                                                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)

            ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                       Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            End If

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                strFolderpath = ""
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            Else
                strFolderpath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)


                ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
                For Each objItem In selItems
                    lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count

                    ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */
                    If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                        Set atmts = objItem.Attachments

                        ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
                        For Each Atmt In atmts

                            ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtFullName = Atmt.FileName

                            ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.
                            intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")

                            ' Get the name.
                            strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                            ' Get the file extension.
                            strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                            ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtPath = strFolderpath & Atmt.FileName

                            ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/
                            If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
                                ' True: This attachment can be saved.
                                blnIsSave = True

                                ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */
                                Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                    strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                      Format(Now, "_mmddhhmmss") & _
                                                      Format(Timer * 1000 Mod 1000, "000")
                                    strAtmtPath = strFolderpath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)

                                    ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/
                                    If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                        lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                        ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.
                                        blnIsSave = False
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop

                                ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */
                                If blnIsSave Then Atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                            Else
                                lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
                    lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If

    ' /* For run-time error:
    '    The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations.
    '    Review your code and restart Outlook. */
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems

    ' /* Release memory. */
    If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
    If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
    If Not (Atmt Is Nothing) Then Set Atmt = Nothing
    If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing

    ' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' #####################
' Convert general path.
' #####################
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' ######################################
' Run this macro for saving attachments.
' ######################################
Public Sub ExecuteSaving()
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim iAttachments As Integer

    For Each oItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    iAttachments = oItem.Attachments.Count + iAttachments
    Next
    MsgBox "Selected " & ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count & " messages with " & iAttachments & " attachements"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use  *[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)* faster to execute and easier to understand.. and more flexible to add additional file types

*After*

```
' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
For Each Atmt In atmts
```

*Simply add*

```
Dim sFileType As String
' Last 4 Characters in a Filename
sFileType = LCase$(Right$(Atmt.FileName, 4))
Debug.Print sFileType

Select Case sFileType
    ' Add additional file types below ".doc", "docx", ".xls"
    Case ".pdf"
```

and before    `Next`

*Add*

```
  End Select
```

Comment: Just FYI, the file extension is already stored in `strAtmtName(1)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
```

to

```
If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH And LCase(strAtmtName(1)) = "pdf" Then
```

---

Full code :

```
' ######################################################
'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.
' ######################################################
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
    Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.
    Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.
    Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.
    Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.
    Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.
    Dim Atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.
    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.
    Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.
    Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.
    Dim strFolderpath       As String       ' The selected folder path.
    Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.
    Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.
    Dim oItem               As Object
    Dim iAttachments        As Integer


    blnIsEnd = False
    blnIsSave = False
    lCountAllItems = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If Err.Number = 0 Then

        ' Get the handle of Outlook window.
        lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)

        If lHwnd <> 0 Then

            ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Select folder to save attachments:", _
                                                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)

            ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                       Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            End If

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                strFolderpath = ""
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            Else
                strFolderpath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)


                ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
                For Each objItem In selItems
                    lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count

                    ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */
                    If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                        Set atmts = objItem.Attachments

                        ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
                        For Each Atmt In atmts

                            ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtFullName = Atmt.FileName

                            ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.
                            intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")

                            ' Get the name.
                            strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                            ' Get the file extension.
                            strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                            ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtPath = strFolderpath & Atmt.FileName

                            ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/
                            If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH And LCase(strAtmtName(1)) = "pdf" Then
                                ' True: This attachment can be saved.
                                blnIsSave = True

                                ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */
                                Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                    strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                      Format(Now, "_mmddhhmmss") & _
                                                      Format(Timer * 1000 Mod 1000, "000")
                                    strAtmtPath = strFolderpath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)

                                    ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/
                                    If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                        lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                        ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.
                                        blnIsSave = False
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop

                                ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */
                                If blnIsSave Then Atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                            Else
                                lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
                    lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If

    ' /* For run-time error:
    '    The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations.
    '    Review your code and restart Outlook. */
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems

    ' /* Release memory. */
    If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
    If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
    If Not (Atmt Is Nothing) Then Set Atmt = Nothing
    If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing

    ' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' #####################
' Convert general path.
' #####################
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' ######################################
' Run this macro for saving attachments.
' ######################################
Public Sub ExecuteSaving()
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim iAttachments As Integer

    For Each oItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    iAttachments = oItem.Attachments.Count + iAttachments
    Next
    MsgBox "Selected " & ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count & " messages with " & iAttachments & " attachements"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank this is now only saving PDF files which is great but it is not saving them all it seems to me missing some. I am trying to save from around 500 emails with about 509 pdf attachements but it is only downloading around 250

Comment: resolved it I had left some code that I was trying in it and it was conflicting.

Thanks very much for your help R3uK

Comment: @StuartJones : You're welcome! ;) BTW, **welcome to SO, please take a minute to see how SO community works by taking the [tour]** (how to accept answers, use votes, and more!) ;)

Comment: @0m3r : Same reflex! ;)