# vba script to save all attachments (PDFs) from outlook then delete the emails

Tags: vba, email, pdf, outlook

I have a bunch of paperwork that I scan in and save everyday. The scanner machine I use sends the scanned paperwork in a PDF format to my inbox, then I open the email, save the PDF, and delete the email I repeat this operation hundreds of times, and it would save me a lot of time if I could automate this process.

So I'm looking for a VBA script for Outlook that will

1. save all the attached PDFs in my inbox to a folder, then
2. delete the emails.

I have seen a lot of postings online that address similar scripts, but everything I've seen so far would only do the first part of the operation, do something similar, or would not work with PDFs.

After doing some searching I found some code online that was similar to what I was looking for. I adapted it to what I wanted it to do and came up with this:

```
Sub getAttachmentsAndDelete()

Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim msg2 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strTmpMsg As String
Dim fsSaveFolder As String

fsSaveFolder = "C:\Users\MikeJones\Documents\Scanned\"

'path for creating attachment msg file for stripping
strFilePath = "C:\Users\MikeJones\Documents\Scanned\temp"
strTmpMsg = "KillMe.msg"

'My testing done in Outlok using a "temp" folder underneath Inbox
Set olFolder =
Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("scanned")

If olFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


For Each msg In olFolder.Items

    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

       While msg.Attachments.Count > 0
          bflag = False
             If Right$(msg.Attachments(1).FileName, 3) = "msg" Then
               bflag = True
               msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile strFilePath & strTmpMsg
               Set msg2 = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & 
                   strTmpMsg)
             End If

             If bflag Then
               msg2.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile fsSaveFolder & 
               msg2.Attachments(1).FileName
               msg2.Delete
             Else
                sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
                msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS
             End If

             msg.Attachments(1).Delete

        Wend

        msg.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

It's a little wacky but gets the job done.  The only issue I had with it was that it would only pull a few emails/files at a time, so I duplicated the loop a couple times and now it will process about 150 emails in one click.

Comment: that last comment makes no sense. it makes no difference what type of a file the attachment is. any code that saves an attachment into a file system directory, will work with attached pdf files.

Comment: The "Related" section on thus page has plenty of working examples.  Try one of those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180639/4539709

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some searching I found some code online that was similar to what I was looking for. I adapted it to what I wanted it to do and came up with this:

```
Sub getAttachmentsAndDelete()

Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSavePath, sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\Scanned\"

Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("scanned")
If olFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For i = olFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set msg = olFolder.Items(i)
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For j = msg.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
                sSavePath = (sSaveFolder & msg.Attachments(j).FileName)
                msg.Attachments(j).SaveAsFile sSavePath
            Next
        End If
    msg.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

This macro gets attachments from messages in my Outlook folder Inbox\scanned and saves them to Documents\scanned on my hard drive.

*edit Nov 2017: Thank you to niton who pointed out a flaw in my solution and suggested using a For loop instead of a For Each loop. I reconstructed my algorithms here and cleaned up the code. This solution doesn't check for attachments inside messages anymore, but does check for multiple attachments in one email, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario there is no point in processing attachments that are mailitems.

```
Sub getAttachmentsAndDelete()

Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
'Dim msg2 As Outlook.MailItem
'Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFilePath As String
'Dim strTmpMsg As String
Dim fsSaveFolder As String

fsSaveFolder = "C:\Users\MikeJones\Documents\Scanned\"

'path for creating attachment msg file for stripping
'strFilePath = "C:\Users\MikeJones\Documents\Scanned\temp"
'strTmpMsg = "KillMe.msg"

'My testing done in Outlok using a "temp" folder underneath Inbox
Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("scanned")

If olFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each msg In olFolder.Items

    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

       While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

          'bflag = False
            ' If Right$(msg.Attachments(1).FileName, 3) = "msg" Then
            '   bflag = True
            '   msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile strFilePath & strTmpMsg
             '  Set msg2 = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & 
             '      strTmpMsg)
            ' End If

            ' If bflag Then
            '   msg2.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile fsSaveFolder & 
            '   msg2.Attachments(1).FileName
            '   msg2.Delete
            ' Else

            '  ** Save any attachment pdf or otherwise **
                sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
                msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS
            ' End If

            ' Deleted attachments cannot be recovered.
            '  Only do so if it is necessary.
            '  Here there is no difference
            '   waiting until the entire message is deleted
            ' msg.Attachments(1).Delete

        Wend

        msg.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Re: Duplicating loops.

`For Each msg In olFolder.Items` is a forward counting loop. You are deleting messages. As all remaining items move up the line you skip the one the loop thinks has just been processed. This leaves half of the items unprocessed each time. When deleting or moving, use a reverse counting loop.

```
For i = olFolder.Items.count to 1 step -1
    Set msg = olFolder.Items(i)
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0
```

or process the first item until zero items remain as demonstrated in the While Wend loop.